# Gdb: can one have non-stop mode for selected threads?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, gdb

I managed to use this non-stop mode for the case when one thread is debugged and others run: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html#Non_002dStop-Mode.

There it's written:

> In non-stop mode, when a thread stops to report a debugging event, only that thread is stopped; GDB does not stop other threads as well, in contrast to the all-stop mode behavior. Additionally, execution commands such as continue and step apply by default only to the current thread in non-stop mode, rather than all threads as in all-stop mode. This allows you to control threads explicitly in ways that are not possible in all-stop mode — for example, stepping one thread while allowing others to run freely, **stepping one thread while holding all others stopped, or stepping several threads independently and simultaneously.**

> You can use GDB’s background execution commands (see Background Execution) to run **some threads in the background while you continue to examine or step others from GDB**. The MI execution commands (see GDB/MI Program Execution) are always executed asynchronously in non-stop mode.

By the link of the [background mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Background-Execution.html#Background-Execution) it's written:

> Background execution is especially useful in conjunction with non-stop mode for debugging programs with multiple threads; see Non-Stop Mode. However, you can also use these commands in the normal all-stop mode with the restriction that you cannot issue another execution command until the previous one finishes. Examples of commands that are valid in all-stop mode while the program is running include help and info break.

But finally I have not found any way to achieve what is highlighted with bold in the paragraphs above. Is it possible to have the non-stop mode for several threads? E.g., debugging two threads while four others run? Also, how can I run one thread in the background while debugging the rest (this possibility is also present in the bold text above, but I don't understand who I can achieve it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-stop mode will apply to all threads, and needs to be set before an inferior is started.

Once an inferior has been started with non-stop mode on, then when the inferior stops or is interrupted (Ctrl-C) only the current thread stops.  Use `info threads` to see the state of all threads.

If you want to resume a single thread and return to the GDB prompt so you can enter further commands, `continue &` is what you want.  Only the currently selected thread will have continued.  You can also `continue -a &` to continue all threads.

If you are at a prompt and wish to interrupt a thread then Ctrl-C will no work, however you can use the `interrupt` command to achieve the same result.

You can change the currently selected thread with `thread N` where N is the ID number of the thread you wish to switch too.

In summary:

- Use `set non-stop on` before starting the inferior,
- Add `&` to the end of continue, or continue like commands to run the command in the background and return to a prompt,
- Use `interrupt` to interrupt a thread when at the prompt,
- Use `info threads` to see the state of all threads,
- Use `thread N` to switch between threads.